# How to hide text watermark

Tags: devexpress, watermark, xtrareport

I've a Devexpress XtraReport and I just couldn't figure out how to hide/show a text `watermark` based on the availability of data. I want "Data Not Available" watermark to be displayed only if data is not available and hide the watermark dynamically if there is some data to display.

What property of the XtraReport should I be considering to hide/show watermark?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this task, handle the [XRControl.BeforePrint](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRControl_BeforePrinttopic) event and modify the the [XtraReport.Watermark Property.](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReport_Watermarktopic)

```
if(report.PrintingSystem.Watermark.TextTransparency == 255)
      report.PrintingSystem.Watermark.TextTransparency = 0;
  else
      report.PrintingSystem.Watermark.TextTransparency = 255;

  printBarManager1.PrintControl.Refresh();
```

Reference these:
[Hide the watermark](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q208434.aspx)
[How to: Change the Visibility of Commands in Preview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument2746)

Comment: Whichever link I give for support of answer, you copy text from there and post as an answer. Good. Thanks for the help!!!!!!

Comment: @RuchiRahulDoshi: you should not just put link in your answer. those links may change in future, so this answer will not be helpful to future visitors. Another thinks is that if you know the exact point to solve the issue then point out with some relevant lines about the SO.  Have a nice time.. Do you work on DevExpress??